# Data Studio CASE error - THEN/ELSE arguments have incompatible types: TEXT/ NUMBER

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I'm trying to change my table dimension name from 1 to "Android", but I get this error message: Invalid formula - THEN/ELSE arguments have incompatible types: TEXT/ NUMBER. All THEN/ELSE arguments must return the same type.

My case statement is below:

CASE
WHEN app_id = 1 THEN 'android'
ELSE app_id END

Comment: What part of the error message do you fail to understand?

Comment: Fully understood the message, just was not sure how to change the integer to a string. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below is divided into two sections, first showing the possible **Issues** and then the **Suggested** [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

## 1) Issues

### 1.1) Incompatible types: TEXT/ NUMBER

The below occurs as `android` is a **Text** value while `app_id` is a **Number** Type field:

```
CASE
  WHEN app_id = 1 THEN 'android'
  ELSE app_id 
END
```

> Invalid formula - THEN/ELSE arguments have incompatible types: TEXT/ NUMBER. All THEN/ELSE arguments must return the same type.

### 1.2) No Functions in THEN/ELSE

This issue results as a *functions or mathematical operation* is used in the `THEN`/`ELSE` section of the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN app_id = 1 THEN 'android'
  ELSE CAST(app_id AS STRING )
END
```

> THEN/ELSE statements cannot contain functions or mathematical operations.

## 2) Suggestions

Either of the [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below does the trick:

### 2.1) RegEx

The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below works with **Text** or **Number** fields:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(app_id AS TEXT),"^(1)$","android")
```

### 2.2) Type: Text

At the Data Source, change the `app_id` field to a **Text** field (duplicate the field if required to maintain a Number and Text field) and use the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN app_id = "1" THEN 'android'
  ELSE app_id
END
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e74769c2-e5e2-4028-b1eb-823ba95acdb2) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, integers and strings are not compatible.  You need to convert the integer to a string:

```
(CASE WHEN app_id = 1 THEN 'android' ELSE CAST(app_id as string) END)
```